# Android external activity fails

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-manifest

I'm trying to set up android multiple file chooser from https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-Multiple-file-Selector-Dialog.
I've added dependency to this library from my project.

Problem is app just fails when I click "run as android application".
Log:

```
[2015-01-30 01:55:19 - PhotoSigner] Android Launch!
[2015-01-30 01:55:19 - PhotoSigner] adb is running normally.
[2015-01-30 01:55:19 - PhotoSigner] Performing com.vladimir.photosigner.MainActivity activity launch
[2015-01-30 01:55:19 - PhotoSigner] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'HT17MV800004'
[2015-01-30 01:55:19 - PhotoSigner] Uploading PhotoSigner.apk onto device 'HT17MV800004'
[2015-01-30 01:55:26 - PhotoSigner] Failed to install PhotoSigner.apk on device 'HT17MV800004': timeout
[2015-01-30 01:55:26 - PhotoSigner] Launch canceled!
```

Here is my android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com`enter code here`.vladimir.photosigner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <activity android:name="paul.arian.fileselector.FileSelectionActivity" />
    <activity android:name="paul.arian.fileselector.FolderSelectionActivity" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.vladimir.photosigner.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my code calling external activity:

import paul.arian.fileselector.FileSelectionActivity;

...

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FileSelectionActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

...

onActivityResult is exactly same as man said in https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-Multiple-file-Selector-Dialog.

Could anyone help with that?